# Reading json efficiently in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am reading around 20,000 JSON files from a folder each file around 10 MB in size. The code below takes about 30 min to read these files.

There are 25 worker nodes of type D4 (Azure HDInsight).

```
var rawJson =  sqlContext.read.json("/data/*.json")
```

Below is the job configuration I am using.

"--driverMemory",
"7g",
"--executorCores",
"3",
"--executorMemory",
"4g",
"--numExecutors",
 "32"

JSON schema looks like this. Different files contain different number of fields in 'properties' section.

```
{  
  "name": "AssetName",
  "time": "2016-06-20T11:57:19.4941368-04:00",
  "data": {
    "type": "EventData",
    "dataDetails": {
      "name": "EventName",
      "measurements": {        
        "StartTime": 61058529,
        "EndTime": 61058737,
        "Duration": 208,
        "ID": 26509812,
        "Version": 24720
      },
      "properties": {
        "identifier": "Foo",
        "EventId": "6b613d8D-2f65-447e-bf6d-9e9133c0b803",
        "TagGuid": "{9E4fe7c1-cf8a-4527-fd27-c0c58c0b1fed}",
        "property1": "val1",
        "property2": "val2",
        "property3": "val3",
        "property4": "False"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are there more efficient/performant ways of reading these json files without adding more resources?

Thanks!

Comment: How many worker machines do you use? What type of disks and files systems? Do you know the schema?

Comment: @mtoto `jsonFile` has been deprecated a long time ago and there is really no reason for it to be faster.

Comment: There are 25 worker machines (D4 type in Azure HDInsights) which uses HDFS file system.

Comment: The simplest possible improvement is to provide schema on read. Do you see anything unexpected in terms of data locality or data distribution after the read?

Comment: Added schema info to the original thread. Will try providing schema on read.

Comment: Specifying the schema on read did the trick! Thanks for the tip zero323!!

Answer (score 0):

The sqlContext.read.json method does not take number of partitions as input. Try creating an RDD[String] and control the parallelism!!!

```
val jsonRDD = sc.textFile("/data/*.json", 100)
val rawJson =  sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD)
```